# NoSuchElementException while looking for image in Camera folder using appium on android emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing a website on `Chrome` (v65) installed on `Android` (7.1.1 API 25).

Chromedriver version 2.37.
`Appium` latest desktop version (v1.5.0, shows server version 1.7.2)

I need to upload an image from the device itself.
Although on the web-browser I am able to upload an image with sendKeys, its not working on the `android emulator`.

This is what the image selection page in the emulator looks like: [image: Images from the Camera Folder]

I used UiAutomator to get the resource id: "com.android.chrome:id/bitmap_view" and the class: "android.widget.ImageView"

I have used the following line(s) of code to try and look for the element:

(a)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'com.android.chrome:id/bitmap_view')]")).click();
```

(b) When I use below, I get an empty list

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");
```

(c) I got this xpath from Appium Inspector Session

```
MobileElement el8 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v7.widget.Af/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ImageView");
el8.click();
```

I don't know what I am missing.

[Update] [[image: UiAutomator showing clickable=false]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44WZE.png)

Comment: Just a suggestion, as I'm not sure it will work, but try using AndroidElement instead of WebElement throughout your app.

Comment: I tried but I got the same error. The Appium logs:
     [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"5b071c0e2075ad5e77f0e5c163df4f2b","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'com.android.chrome:id/bitmap_view')]\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)"}}
[info]

Comment: I just noticed that in UiAutomator it says clickable  = false. Is there a way I can change it to clickable?
I have added the image in my post

Comment: I also tried TouchActions, but with that I am getting 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented

TouchAction a=new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
Duration d=Duration.ofMillis(1000);
a.press(750,420).waitAction(d).moveTo(993,420).release().perform();

Comment: Your error message mentions chromedriver - is this a web app, native app, or hybrid?  If this is a web page you'd need to change the context and use the regular xpath.

Comment: It is a web page.
The context seems to be the same : CHROMIUM  
I checked when the image folder opened up 
System.out.println(driver.getContext());

Comment: I did try to use the xpath as I mentioned in the post under option (a)

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'com.android.chrome:id/bitmap_view')]")).click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the context to the **NATIVE_APP** in your test?

Since you mentioned you test chrome, it means your test is using **WEBVIEW** context. But as soon as you open Upload files screen it is a **NATIVE_APP** view and you need to switch to it before start searching:

```
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(
            new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.get(<your_web_site>);
// do what you need in browser, open Upload files screen

// switch to Native context to search inside it
Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String context : contexts) {
    System.out.println(contexts);
    if (context.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {
        driver.context(context);
        break;
    }
}
List<MobileElement> images = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");
// click the last image in view if exist
images.stream()
    .reduce((first, second) -> second)
    .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new)
    .click();
```